# Database file structure and indexes and implementation

Tags: java, c, database, tree, indexing

I have been reading about how database indexes are implemented and database files are organized from Silberschatz.
The description is about trees that point directly to disk blocks and describe how these trees minimize block access.
But I don't get this description. I mean the trees (B or B+) are implemented in some application language e.g C/C++ (perhaps Java) right?
So how can a disk block can be referenced by such a tree structure? Can anyone help clearing this out?

Answer (score 1):

To say that (the leaves of) the trees point directly at disk blocks seems a bit misleading.  I'd expect that what is meant is that a 'block index' is stored in the leaves of the trees - and probably then an index to a particular block (of some size) within a file, rather than a disk.

Comment: You mean offsets to a file?

Comment: No - offsets within a file.  Note, however, that I'm thinking along the lines of a "modern" database (last thirty or so years... ahem) - perhaps at one point, disk offset was used.